# Strange sound of low frequency produced from 2 steel balls

Tags: forces, acoustics, contact-mechanics

When two steel balls collide, or any metal objects collide, a high frequency sound is produced.  However, what was strange is that when I held two metal balls in my hand, and moved them around, it produces a rather strange sound when they collide.  This sound, is of a low frequency, maybe only hundreds of hertz.  What surprises me is not only the low frequency,  but also how this strange sound is produced.  Is there anyone who can explain this phenomenon to me?

Comment: Possibly the two balls repeatedly bouncing off each other?

Comment: I agree with Ben51, since that sound is kind of similar to the buzz you get when a coin that's spinning on its edge on a hard surface finally settles down. Also, by holding the balls you will damp a lot of the vibrations, especially the high frequency components.

Comment: Surely the two balls repeatedly bouncing off each other!